# Module and square of a complex number

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, discrete-mathematics, complex-numbers

if I have the square module of a complex number, how can I solve it?
Example:

$|e^{-1}\cos(2 \pi f t)-e^{-1}j\sin(2 \pi f t)-1|^2$

First idea:
$[e^{-1}\cos(2 \pi f t)]^2 +[-e^{-1}\sin(2 \pi f t)-1] ^2$  theoretically   $a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+2bc$

Second idea:
$[e^{-1}\cos(2 \pi f t) -e^{-1}\sin(2 \pi f t)-1] ^2$  theoretically  $ a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}-2ab+2bc-2ac $

what is the correct solution?
Thanks

Comment: $\forall (a+b\mathrm{i}) \in \mathbb{C}$, $|a+b\mathrm{i}|^2=a^2+b^2.$
**Hint**: separate your complex number into its real and imaginary components.

Comment: thanks @K.defaoite for your answer... so for you the correct solution is the second?

Comment: No. I'll refer to the complex number in question as $z$. We can see that $\text{Re}(z)=e^{-1}\cos(2\pi ft)-1$ and $\text{Im}(z)=e^{-1}\sin(2\pi ft)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|z|^2=\Re^2z+\Im^2z=(r\cos\theta-1)^2+(r\sin\theta)^2.$$

You can rewrite as

$$r^2-2r\cos\theta+1.$$

---

Here it is not a very good idea to square *before* taking the modulus. If you want to, the correct way is

$$(a-ib+c)^2=a^2-b^2+c^2-2iab+2ac-2ibc$$

and

$$|a-ib+c|^2=\sqrt{(a^2-b^2+c^2+2ac)^2+(2ab+2bc)^2}.$$

If you aggreate $s:=a+c$,

$$\sqrt{(s^2-b^2)^2+(2sb)^2}=\sqrt{s^4+2s^2b^2+b^4}=s^2+b^2.$$

Comment: this is the answer that I hope to find! So when I have somethink like that I can rewrite like real part with square and imaginary part with square... perfect... In my exercise I have wrong the position of the $1$ that I have aggregated with the $sin()$ function infact I have: $e^{-2}+1+2e^{-1}sin(2 \pi ft)$

Comment: If a correct way is to separate the real part and immaginary part, I would follow your first solution... I think that it's really fast and during an exam, the time is like money :D

Comment: I follow your first solution... It's clear, and equal to many found in exercise solutions of my collegue... Thank you very much